# Access init-param

Tags: primefaces

How do i access an init-param value in a web.xml ? I need to retrieve my upload file location.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param>
        <param-name>dir</param-name>
        <param-value>some path</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to retrieve the param value from? I haven't used the fileupload in Primefaces but I would expect that information would be available in the UploadedFile class. You should be able to get the information you are looking for on your backing bean. Check the user manual for detailed information.

Comment: Hi Steve. yes i am trying to access it from the backing bean. FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String value = ctx.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("directory");

Answer (score 0):

If you are just need to find out where a file was dropped you may be able to do something like this on your backing bean. I am not sure if the file name will contain the directory information or not:

```
public void uploadListener(FileUploadEvent upLoad){
    UploadedFile myFile = upLoad.getFile();
    String myFileName = myFile.getFileName();

    System.out.println(myFileName);
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve Thank you for the help. i have just decided to extract my upload location from my web.xml using a context -param instead of an init-param. The reason for doing this is so that the upload location is not hard coded in my backing bean.